# How to capture the image without showing Camera View in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to create an app in which i want to capture the image by camera but would'nt like to open the camera view (How to hide the camera View during capturing image)..plz help me...!!

Answer (score 0):

the Answer is the AVFoundation framework . the Apple also provide a sample project named AVCam that can teach you how to record a video with AVFoundation framework API.